# Get country and state name from lat and lng in Geocode

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am a newbie in web development. Today, I am trying to use Google Map API to get the country name and the state name from longitude and latitude using JavaScript. I read the documentation from the Google Map API and did some research but I was kinda confused about this. I gave it a go and this is what I did:

```
function getCountryName(latitude, longitude){
    var country;
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({location: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}}, (results, status) => {
        if(status === "OK"){
            if(results[0]){
                country = results[0].address_components[0].types[0].country;
            }
            else{
            country = "N/A";
            }
        }
    });
    return country;
}
```

However, I keep getting the "undefine" result. Is there anything wrong with my approach?
Thanks you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the asynchronous programming happening here.

Basically you have `return country;` statement at the end of function execution which will always be undefined since the results haven't been fetched by that time.

The 2nd parameter that you are sending to the `geocoder.geocode` is a callback function that will be called once google has fetched the results which obviously takes a little bit of time.

So your function should be something like this

```
function getCountryName(latitude, longitude, onSucess){
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({location: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}}, (results, status) => {
        if(status === "OK"){
            if(results[0]){
                onSucess(results[0].address_components[0].types[0].country);
            }
            else{
                onSucess("N/A");
            }
        }
    });
    return country;
}
```

And when you are about to use this function elsewhere, you have to use it like this

```
getCountryName(1.1111, 2.2222, (country) => {
    alert(country);
    console.log(country);
    // You can do anything here like showing it to ui or using it elsewhere
}
```

If you want to learn more about callbacks in JS, go through this [Article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced).